# Opening and beginning

Tags: word-usage

Fill in the gap: "... of the document". This refers to "the start of the document". I had 2 choices: "opening" and "beginning". I chose "opening" but the answer is "beginning". Why?

Comment: Google both "beginning of the document" and "opening of the document" and compare the results (as in: read the actual passages where these clauses appear and do a comparative evaluation). Having done that, review the relevant drift ions of these two words in your dictionary, and the distinctions it draws out will be much clearer to you.

Comment: @DanBron Easy for you to say (and likely do).

Comment: Not everything you are taught is correct. Question everything!

Answer (score 0):

*Beginning* carries the meaning of the start of something, spatially

> The **beginning** of Fifth Avenue is Washington Square Park.

or temporally

> Let's wait until the **beginning** of the year.

*Opening* can have the same usage:

> A murder occurs at the **opening** of the novel.

But *opening* also has other, contrasting meanings, often of an initial action.  Thus the **opening** of a bridge means the ceremony at the start of its usage by traffic, while the **beginning** of a bridge is the first part of its physical construction.

The **opening** of a play is the first performance in a run; the **beginning** of play is the first line of the first scene of the first act.

The **opening** of a book could be the act of turning to a page in the book; the **beginning** of a book is its first page.

The **opening** of a document could be the start of a word processing program on the document; the **beginning** of a document is its first paragraph.

For the physical start of something, use *beginning* to avoid confusion with the other connotations of *opening*.